# Can't run docker image with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I'm using Docker+MongoDB to run a Personal Project (tutorial i'm learning from). It worked flawlessly yesterday, but i had to restart my computer today.

Now i can't get it up & running again. I'm always having the error (according to the logs):
EDIT: The same error happens when i try to run it locally also (just compiling and checking on Postman if i can run any query). Its the same error message.
EDIT2: After running:

> docker run -d --rm --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v mongodbdata:/data/db
> mongo

I got it working locally. However, i still can't get it running using the docker image.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "0HML25FGS5AM1", Request id "0HML25FGS5AM1:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
> application.
> System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is {
> ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
> [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongo:27017"
> }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongo:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat",
> State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type:
> "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server.

Here's what i can tell:

1. MongoDB is running. On Visual Studio using Mongo Extension, i can see that my mongo database is connected.
2. When i open docker for windows, i can see my image there as well. And if i hover the mouse under docker icon on notification tray, it says that docker is running.
3. My connection string seems to be okay. I couldn't figure out any problem with that, since its the same that was working yesterday.

I'm a bit of lost here, i don't know what else to do. It would be really really painful to restart the entire tutorial because of this docker error.

Here is my connection string:

```
$"mongodb://{User}:{Password}@{Host}:{Port}";
```

The command i'm using under the cli to run my docker image is:

> docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 -e MongoDbSettings:Host=mongo -e
> MongoDbSettings:Password=Pass#word1 --network=net5tutorial
> pablobhz/catalog:v1

Any input is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's your actual connection string?  It's not this: $"mongodb://{User}:{Password}@{Host}:{Port}";

Comment: That's my connection string (the one i use at MongoDbSettings.cs). If i were to replace the variables it would be: $"mongodb://mongoadmin:Pass#word1@localhost:27017"; . This is what i get when running locally (F5).

Comment: everytime you call `docker run` you are redeploying a container.  You also refer to a non-ephemeral storage volume `-v mongodbdata:/data/db mongo`.  My recommendation is to clear out all existing containers created when using `docker run`, then clear out the volume at `/data/db`, then try `docker run` again.  After you get the docker container running, don't deploy with 'docker run` again.  Instead start and stop the container.

Comment: Just did it. Started the image using Docker for Windows (just clicked run, no additional parameters). When i check containers, its listed there as running. However, when i try to access it i just receive a connection refused. When checking details, its okay also (info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80). EDIT: Removed the container, changed the port to 8080 and tried to run again. Same error, something related to MOngoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i fixed the problem myself. Here's what i did:

1. Followed the suggestion from user barrypicker . It didn't worked out but gave me an clean start.
2. Created a new docker file and changed it accordingly (only minor changes).
3. Created the mongodb container again. Here's what i did:

> docker run -d --rm --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v mongodbdata:/data/db mongo

Fine. Now i have the mongo container running again.

4. Built my docker image again:

> ```
> docker build -t catalog:v1 .
> ```

5. Tried to create the docker network again. Since it already existed, just received a message saying it exists. So far so good.
6. Started the mongo container again. I understood that i had to start in order to my docker image works. It can't connect to an database if there's none running.

> docker run -d --rm --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v mongodbdata:/data/db
> /e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e
> MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=Pass#word1 --network=net5tutorial mongo

7. Started the main container again:

> docker run --it --rm -p 8080:80 -e MongoDbSettings:Host=mongo -e
> MongoDbSettings:Password=Pass#word1 --network=net5tutorial catalog:v1

Hope this helps someone in the future! Sorry fot eh explanation not being great, its my first time with Docker and i've been into a lot of trial and error to get it working.

Thanks everyone!